# Does Kindle (classic) support all embedded fonts in PDFs?

Tags: kindle, pdf, fonts, i18n

I have PDFs using many embedded fonts from many alphabets.

Should I expect them to be viewed without any problems on Kindle, or only a part of them will be supported (for the most popular alphabets)?